# Кто нибудь знает как сделать отсчет времени в Python? Посоветуйте какой-нибудь модуль или команду

Tags: python, python-3.x

Кто нибудь знает как сделать отсчет времени в Python? Посоветуйте какой-нибудь модуль или команду, Python3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего вам подойдёт [модуль time](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html?highlight=time#module-time)

Answer (score 0):

```
import time

timer = time.time()

while True:
 
    if time.time() - timer > 10:       # 10 - секунды таймера 
        print('hello world')
        break
```